What if dark matter and anti-matter collided?
Considering we know both dark matter and antimatter can interact via gravity, just like regular matter, then that means the two can gravitationally interact. However,
since dark matter does not interact via electromagnetic force, a collision between the two could not be like regular matter & antimatter collision, where the end result is photons, so then what exactly would the collision of dark matter and anti-matter result in?

Dark matter might also act weakly, eg WIMPs, so there are many interactions that might happen...but it of course still boils down to what the answer stated

We know what happens when one form of dark matter collides with normal matter because neutrinos are a form of dark matter. They cannot be the form of dark matter responsible for the rotation curves of galaxies because there aren't enough of them, but if dark matter is made from WIMPs their reactions are likely to be similar.

No one knows what dark matter actually is yet, so the best you could do is pick your favorite model for what dark matter is, and see what happens.
